# Expression must be modifiable lvalue problem while simplifiying the legacy code

Tags: c

I have a legacy as below.

```
#define dev_a 0
#define dev_b 0
#define dev_c 1 /*Opens code blocks belongs to dev_c*/

#if  dev_a
        query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_a = 1U;
#endif
#if dev_b
        query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_b = 1U;
#endif
#if dev_c
        query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_c = 1U;
#endif
```

This code block are called many times in the software,  in each time calling this block reduces the readability. I tried a lot of types of macro that simplify this block, but everytime I got stuck in lvalue problem.
Compiler says Lvalue must be modifiable value.
I tried something like this :

```
in .h

#define LOG_AMBIENT_LOW_TEMP(SELECT_DEVICE) 
(SELECT_DEVICE == 0x00) ? query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_a:\
(SELECT_DEVICE == 0x02) ? query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_b : query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_c

in.c

uint16_t Device = DEVSEL; /* Parsing from somewhere*/
LOG_AMBIENT_LOW_TEMP(Device) = 1U; /*Fails Due to the Lvalue problem*/
```

this macro fails due to the "lvalue must be modifiable"

I am open to any ideas which fullfils the work that this legacy block did above in a single line.

Comment: what is `lvalue` problem? what did you try?

Comment: This honestly looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: please describe the effect that you want to achieve

Comment: Pease provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this:

```
LOG_AMBIENT_LOW_TEMP(Device) = 1U;
```

Expands to this:

```
(Device == 0x00) ? query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_a:\
(Device == 0x02) ? query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_b :query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_c = 1U;
```

This puts the result of the ternary operator on the left side of an assignment.  Unlike C++, the result of the ternary operator does not result in an lvalue and therefore can't be on the left side of an assignment.

What you can do, assuming the relevant fields are of the same type, is to take the address of each field referenced in the ternary, then dereference the result.  That will give you an lvalue:

```
#define LOG_AMBIENT_LOW_TEMP(SELECT_DEVICE) 
*((SELECT_DEVICE == 0x00) ? &query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_a:\
  (SELECT_DEVICE == 0x02) ? &query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_b : &query.warning.bit.lowtemp_dev_c)
```